# Why does converting to `list` improve the performance of `lapply`?

Tags: r, performance, vector, vectorization, lapply

I am surprised to see the first line runs much slower compared to the second one, which is suspiciously close in performance to the vectorized version. If processing a list is so much faster than processing a `numeric(n)` vector, why doesn't R convert its input to a list automatically?

```r
> system.time(lapply(1:10^7, sqrt))
   user  system elapsed
  4.445   0.204   4.692
> system.time(lapply(list(1:10^7), sqrt))
   user  system elapsed
  0.048   0.015   0.062
> system.time(sqrt(1:10^7))
   user  system elapsed
   0.04    0.00    0.04
```

Here is the version information

```
$ R --version
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.3.1
BuildVersion:   21E258
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the second expression is just a `list` of length 1

```
> length(list(1:10^7))
[1] 1
```

which is basically the same as applying `sqrt` directly.  Instead, if we want to do this purely on each element of a `list`, it would require `as.list` instead of `list` i.e.

```
> length(as.list(1:10^7))
[1] 10000000
```

---

Converting to `list` from `vector` is unnecessary if the intention is to loop over each element of vector.  In a `vector`, each element is a unit (same with `matrix` - only having `dim` attributes), but in a data.frame/tibble/data.table, each unit is a column.  Thus, `lapply` loops over the unit i.e. column in data.frame where as the single element in a `vector`.  When we wrap a vector with `list`, it is encapsulating the whole vector as a single `list` element

```
> list(1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

> as.list(1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

As `sqrt` is a vectorized function, the when we apply the `sqrt` by looping over the first `list`, it loops only once, but in second, it loops multiple times.

---

Thus, we get similar timings (of course the extra timing will be to convert the vector to `list` with `as.list`)

```
>  system.time(lapply(1:10^7, sqrt))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.364   0.220   4.748 
> system.time(lapply(as.list(1:10^7), sqrt))
   user  system elapsed 
  4.882   0.367   5.518
```

A faster option would be to use `vapply` (if we are applying non-vectorized functions on a loop)

```
> system.time(vapply(1:10^7, sqrt, numeric(1)))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.464   0.172   2.633
```

Comment: So it's due to the overhead in calling functions multiple times?

Comment: @danlooo yes, it is calling multiple times when it should be called oncee as `sqrt` is vectorized